# Bind Kendo UI Grid to List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

The Kendo UI Grid just renders the column headers.

Grid does not render the actual data rows in the grid.

Here is my code.

```
 public class CalculatorController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult TimberData_Read()
    {
        var grades = new List<TimberGrades>();
        grades.Add(new TimberGrades() { TimberGrade = "C14", BendingParallelToGrain = 4.1 });
        grades.Add(new TimberGrades() { TimberGrade = "C16", BendingParallelToGrain = 5.3 });

        var result = grades.AsQueryable();
        return Json(result);
    }
}

public class TimberGrades
{
    public string TimberGrade { get; set; }
    public double BendingParallelToGrain { get; set; }

    public TimberGrades()
    {
        TimberGrade = "C14";
        BendingParallelToGrain = 4.1;
    }
}
```

Inside my view, I try to render the Grid as follows:

```
<div id="DivTimberGradeGrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TimberBeamCalculator.Models.TimberGrades>()
        .Name("TimberGradeGrid")
        .DataSource(ds => ds
                        .Ajax()
                        .Read(r => r.Action("TimberData_Read", "Calculator"))   
        )
        .Columns(c=> 
                    {
                        c.Bound(t => t.TimberGrade);
                        c.Bound(t => t.BendingParallelToGrain);
                    }
        )
    )


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out myself.

In my controller class:

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;

.....

        public ActionResult TimberData_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var grades = new List<TimberGrades>();
            grades.Add(new TimberGrades() { TimberGrade = "C14", BendingParallelToGrain = 4.1 });
            grades.Add(new TimberGrades() { TimberGrade = "C16", BendingParallelToGrain = 5.3 });

            IQueryable<TimberGrades> res = grades.AsQueryable<TimberGrades>();
            DataSourceResult res1 = res.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(res1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

....

and in the view


        <p>
            <div id="DivTimberGradeGrid">
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TimberBeamCalculator.Models.TimberGrades>()
                    .Name("TimberGradeGrid")
                    .DataSource(ds => ds
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Read(r => r.Action("TimberData_Read", "Calculator"))   
                    )
                    .Columns(c=> 
                            {
                                c.Bound(t => t.TimberGrade);
                                c.Bound(t => t.BendingParallelToGrain);
                            }
                    )
                )


            </div>
        </p>
```

Comment: Why aren't you passing the Model to the page and then rendering your grid from the model instead of having the server render the page, to then execute an ajax request back to the server to get a set of json data for the grid? If you passed the model to the page from the action that landed you on the page, you wouldn't have to do a follow up ajax request to get the data.